# Почему все-таки что-то достать из-за пазухи, а не из пазухи?

Tags: предлоги

Пазуха - это пространство между грудью и одеждой. Значит достают что-то из чего-то/откуда-то - из пазухи, из этого самого пространства. Когда как "из-за" : "соединяя в себе значения предлогов «из» и «за», обозначает направление действия или движения откуда-либо и притом с обратной или с другой, противоположной, стороны чего-либо ◆ Смотреть из-за двери. ◆ Из-за стены слышны голоса. ◆ Выскочить из-за угла. ◆ Из-за облака опять выплыла луна. А. П. Чехов ◆ Приехал из-за мо́ря. ◆ Из-за границы".
Так почему именно из-за пазухи?

Comment: Думаю, "из-за" здесь используется нестандартно. Не как единый предлог из-за, а как два отдельных предлога из и за. Сравните: "Он летел по-над пропастью" = "он летел над пропастью". Аналогично "Он достал из-за пазухи" = "Он достал из пазухи"

Comment: Потому что находящееся "за" пазухой можно достать только "из-за" (если то не пазуха носа, "в" которой что-нибудь находится). Исследовать нужно исходное выражение "за пазухой". По Фасмеру, одно из этим. значений пазухи - _предплечье_. Вероятно, "за" ним что-то и прячут.

Comment: Пазухи бывают разные. Если что-то находится в гайморовой пазухе, пазухе носа, пазухе листа, то достается из пазухи. Если находится за пазухой, то и достается из-за пазухи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут, на мой взгляд, имеет место неверное использование слова «пазуха».

Как вы правильно заметили:

- «Пазуха — это пространство между грудью и одеждой»;
- «…„из-за“: …обозначает направление действия или движения откуда-либо и притом с обратной или с другой, противоположной, стороны
  чего-либо».

Когда говорят «из-за пазухи», имеют в виду «из-за обратной стороны одежды в районе груди». Возможно, так стали говорить ещё из-за того, что «из-за пазухи» легче произнести, чем «из пазухи».

Comment: @Александр Стрелец Спасибо за исправления!